# Does MDM interfere with keychain sharing between iOS apps?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mdm

I have a set of apps that will be using a shared keychain to store some sensitive information between them. The will have the same bundle seed ID, of course.

These apps will be MDM-wrapped before they are deployed, using Airwatch or Maas360. Will the keystore sharing still work when the apps are wrapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will still work. Apple doesn't introduce any automatic MDM functionality that will start barring communication between the shared keystore nor will it report the contents of said Keystore. Off the top of my head I don't think Apples allows it to be toggled off manually, either.